# Wordpress: search error message in several languages

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am building a multilanguage Wordpress website, is it possible to display a different error message for each language when a search returns no results and how?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you use any wordpress plugin to make `multilanguage` or not?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the plugins and the template you are using. I can sugest the following link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Many modern templates come with .po files that allow easy internationalization of most text elements such as search and results that you are looking for. Same happens with plugins, if they follow good practices you should be able to translate/internationalize everything you need.